# Can I skip a scenario in karate beforeScenario hook, if my pre condition is failed

Tags: karate

eg: [How do I use TestNG SkipException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591712/how-do-i-use-testng-skipexception)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/71978154/143475